# Complex Number - Find all roots of the equation

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

### $$e^{i \frac{{\pi}}{3}}z^5+4e^{i\frac{(2+3){\pi}}{6}}z^3 + z^2 + 4i = 0.$$

By using Euler's formula, I got:

$$e^{i \frac{{\pi}}{3}} = \cos{\frac {\pi}{3}} + i\sin{\frac {\pi}{3}} = (\frac{1}{2} + i{\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2}}) $$

$$4e^{i  \frac{(2+3){\pi}}{6}} = 4(\cos{\frac {5\pi}{6}} + i\sin{\frac {5\pi}{6}}) = 4 ({\frac {-\sqrt{3}}{2}} + i \frac{1}{2}) $$

but how do i proceed from here? Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: This is a quintic and since there is no general formula for its roots by means of radicals of its coefficients and there doesn't *seem* to be a more or less obvious trick...well, good luck! Perhaps you can try some approximation methods...?

Comment: Does the second term have a $z^4$ attached to it or is it just a constant? It's just that the ordering seems a little strange if it is the latter.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan thanks for pointing it out! i made a mistake in the question. there's no z^4 but the second term should be attached to z^3 instead of an addition

Comment: Ok. And why have you written $(2+3)\pi$ and not $5\pi$?

Comment: it was just the way the qns was given..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The polynomial can be factored as

$$
e^{i\pi/3} (z^3+a)(z^2+b).
$$

**More:** Multiply it out:

$$
e^{i\pi/3} (z^3+a)(z^2+b) = e^{i\pi/3}z^5+be^{i\pi/3}z^3 + ae^{i\pi/3}z^2 + abe^{i\pi/3}.
$$

To make this match the original polynomial, $e^{i\pi/3}z^5 + 4e^{i5\pi/6}z^3 + z^2 + 4i$, we need

$$
be^{i\pi/3} = 4e^{i5\pi/6}, \qquad ae^{i\pi/3} = 1, \qquad abe^{i\pi/3} = 4i.
$$

From the first equation we get

$$
b = 4e^{i3\pi/6} = 4i
$$

and from the second we get

$$
a = e^{i5\pi/3}.
$$

Thus

$$
e^{i\pi/3}z^5 + 4e^{i5\pi/6}z^3 + z^2 + 4i = e^{i\pi/3}(z^3 + e^{i\pi/3})(z^2+4i).
$$

Now just solve

$$
z^3 + e^{i\pi/3} = 0
$$

and

$$
z^2+4i = 0
$$

to find the roots of the equation.

Comment: Hi, would it be possible for you to elaborate more? Thanks!

Comment: @KillerKidz I've added a little more.